# Replacing strings with digits automatically

Tags: r

I have a pretty huge data frame with a column in which some personal emails are repeated hundred times, such as (please see figure below):

[image]

is there a function/package which can handle this automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: may use `dense_rank()` as well

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
x <- c("a","a","b","b","v","w") #your emails
numbers <- as.numeric(as.factor(x))
```

or

```
numbers <- match(x,unique(x))
```